Hand structure of a 4D person?
Consider this a long overdue follow-up to Limb structure of a 4D creature.
The ancestors of our 4D people have limbs with a complex hip/shoulder which can rotate in any of six planes (XY, YZ, ZW, XZ, XW, and YW), just as our can rotate in three (pitch [XY], yaw [XZ], and roll [YZ], assuming X is the limb length axis); simple knee/shoulder joints which are designed to bend in the up-forward plane; and wrist/ankle joints which can rotate in at least the three planes that do not contain the limb length axis, and may or may not be able to rotate in the three hyper-roll planes (i.e., the three planes which are perpendicular to the limb length axis; if the limb length axis is X, these would be the YZ, YW, and ZW planes).
This allows the hip/shoulder to provide motive force to position the end of the limb in any direction along a 3D surface, and to lift it above the surface; the knee/elbow to shorten the length between hip/shoulder and hand/foot, and to provide mechanical advantage in the direction of motion; and the ankle joint to permit an attached foot to tilt to conform to whatever surface it is on.
But, this leaves the possible structures of a foot, and of a hand that may later evolve from a foot, unspecified.
There seem to be two possible ways to arrange fingers/toes on the end of a 3D animal's limb: attached in a linear array, extending outward in parallel from the palm, like our fingers are; or arranged radially around the end of the arm, like... nothing actually is, although some birds start to approach that arrangement with one or two backwards-facing toes. Parallel toes can lengthen into parallel fingers which can wrap around to enclose a volume, but grasping is improved by rotating at least one digit away from parallel in a rough approximation of the radial arrangement, thus producing an opposable thumb.
In 4D, there are more possibilities. You could have a two-flat palm and finger array just like we have in 3D... but that kind of foot structure in 4D would be like walking on the edge of your toe in 3D. Doesn't feel likely. The higher-dimensional equivalent of our knuckles being in a line with fingers extending out in parallel would be to have an array of knuckles in a plane, with fingers extending out from that plane. That 3D block of fingers could then curl in the 4th dimension to enclose a hypercylindrical bulk (hypervolume)--but presumably, some sort of opposition would be better.
The analog of a regular radial arrangement of digits would be a polyhedral arrangement--4 tetrahedrally-arranged digits, 6 cubically-arranged digits, 8 octahedrally-arranged digits, 12 dodecohedrally-arranged digits, 20 icosahedrally-arranged digits, or any other number in a less-regular pattern, really. And those could also curve around in different directions to enclose a polychoroidal bulk with opposition.
And then both of those basic geometrically-simple options can be modified both with irregulairty (i.e., our knuckle joints are not all perfectly identical, why should those of a 4D animal be?) and by making use of the fourth dimension to alter the attachment angles of digits.
So: What sort of structure makes the most sense for a 4D land creature's feet, and how would that translate into a sensible structure for a 4D person's hands?
Edits for JBH:

if my 3D foot is suitable to stand on a basically 2D surface then it
would help for you to describe a 4D street from the perspective of its
surface....

Gladly. A 4D street has a 3D surface. It may be roughly cylindrical, or in the shape of a prism; one might imagine a square cross-section as reasonable extrapolation of our rectangular roads, and square or hexagonal cross sections make it easy to pack together arrays of multiple lanes"; however, a less technologically advanced roadway is likely to be more cylindrical, with either built up crest running through the center to shed rain if it is a purpose-built road, just like our roads are crowned in the center, or else a cylindrical run carved out of the middle if it is a naturally-worn path, just as we have ruts worn in the middle of our 2D-surfaced footpaths. The texture and contours of the surface extends into the 4th dimension; you could usefully imagine it as in a 3D projection via false-coloring or opacity. A creature walking on a 4D road can move freely throughout the 3D space of the cylinder / prism, without ever leaving contact with the ground--and wherever it does make contact with the ground, that contact is spread over a 3D surface volume, rather than 2D surface area.

Can you describe what a 4D sphere is like? I know what my hand must be
structured like to grasp, say, an apple... but what does a 4D apple
look like?

A 4D sphere is a volume, all of whose points are equidistant from a common center, and which encloses a 4-dimensional bulk, all of whose points are closer to that center. It's a very straightforward generalization of the 0-sphere (two points equidistant from a center point on a 1D line), to the 1-sphere (a circle, all of whose points are equidistant from a center point in a 2D plane), to the 2-sphere (the familiar sphere in 3 dimensions, a 2D surface which encloses a 3D volume), anbd then on to the 3-sphere, which lives in 4D. Each cross-section of a 4D sphere is itself a 3D sphere, just as each cross-section of a 3D sphere is a circle (i.e., a 2D sphere, 1-sphere, or circle). Apples aren't really all that round, so it's not completely obvious how to extend them into 4D, but a 4D orange, for example, could be an stack of an infinite number of 3D oranges (each of which has infinitesimal width in the 4th dimension), starting small and getting larger towards the middle, and then tapering off again on the other side.

What makes the most sense and what actually evolves can be two very different things.  Give us a starting point, and we may be able to come up with something that is workable from start to finish.  Remember that every evolutionary step has to be more advantageous than its predecessor, or it can't evolve.

I'm a fan of a line from Men In Black 3, "What do you know and what do you don't know?" asks J. "How the hell do I know what I don't know?" answers K. Or perhaps a less subtle hint is "how much wood would a wood chuck chuck if a wood chuck could chuck wood?" ... "He would chuck all the wood that a wood chuck could chuck if a wood chuck could chuck wood." I'm having enough trouble imagining four 90° angles... but curiously, if my 3D foot is suitable to stand on a basically 2D surface then it would help for you to describe a 4D street from the perspective of its surface....

Oh... I just noticed I used the simpler question of a 4D foot. Sorry. Can you describe what a 4D sphere is like? I know what my hand must be structured like to grasp, say, an apple... but what does a 4D apple look like? (In many ways the trivial answer is going to be, "you have an opposable thumb extending into the 4th dimension" but, seriously, I'm having trouble imagining a dimension I can't experience.)

A 4D creature could not even have simple bilateral body plan as most complex animals do and still be a complex creature anyway because there is an extra dimension out there giving it an extra degree of freedom. So, the result could be much more complicated than what we think of.

@VictorStafusa See https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/149230/body-plan-of-a-4d-human-analog
Bilateral symmetry is absolutely possible in 4D; the body is simply reflected across a volume rather an a plane. But that does turn out to probably not be the ideal form in most cases.

@JBH Edited to address your background questions.

Those are bad descriptions. If a 3D street is one that basically allows us to step on its 2D surface in both directions at the same time, then a 4D street is one that "basically" allows us to step on all three dimensions at the same time. I can't imagine that and your description does not describe that. You're just describing 3D shapes with the same 2D surfaces as the street.

@JBH No, I'm not. The 3D shapes are the surface. The 4D street allows you to step in all three directions because its surface is 3-dimensional. The "surfaces" of those 3D shapes are the boundary of the road--just like the boundaries of our roads are borderlines. If you are incapable of imagining that, that's not my problem; I don't know how you would expect me to improve your imaginative ability. But that is in fact what I am describing.

However, I will say that the difficulty of imagining 4D objects is why I try to direct most of my thinking in this space towards understanding the mathematics of their geometry and physical interactions, which can be objectively described, and deriving impressionistic descriptions for Spacelanders from that basis, rather than relying on mental visualization from the start.

@JBH This short book might help: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Patrick-Powers-3/publication/359213812_Elsewhere_Everyday_Life_On_A_Hypergeometric_Earth/links/622f3734441164564a748aa5/Elsewhere-Everyday-Life-On-A-Hypergeometric-Earth.pdf

It is scant on some details, and sadly Patrick has never published the promised follow-up volumes, but I think it does do a good job of explaining how 4D roads, tracks, and swimming lanes work, with illustrations (which are of course missing from my explanation).

As per Pelinore's comment
5D Hand
Basically to a 4D being, we can't really see the last dimension but just imagine it as a ghost where the ghost's hand can either grab something or move through something.
The fifth dimension means different objects can occupy the same four dimensions we enjoy but a different fifth dimension.
